# restrict 30 characters display on screen followed by 3 dots by css

Tags: html, css

Its a filter we are applying in left panel of application, in-case that string is longer than 31 characters we want to restrict it to 31 characters including white-space, using HTML/CSS only.

CSS Code:

```
div.filter-search
div.collapse 
div.search-optionfilter 
ul.chosen-choices 
.badge{
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     max-width: 31ch;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you missed `display:inline-block` property

and`div.filter-search` class is missing

```css
div.collapse div.search-optionfilter ul.chosen-choices li.search-choice div.badge { white-space: nowrap; 
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
max-width: 31ch; 
display: inline-block;
width: 31ch; 
background-color: #eeeeee;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 4px 20px 4px 10px; 
color: #151b1e; 
font-size: 12px;
font-family: arial; 
margin-right: 6px; 
} 
.badge {
  min-width: 10px; 
  line-height: 1; 
  vertical-align: baseline; 
}
```

```html
<div id="search-filter1" class="collapse in"> 
  <div class="filter-margin">
    <div class="search-optionfilter">
      <span class="activeFiltersCross">Active Filters:</span>
      <ul class="chosen-choices">
        <li class="search-choice"> 
          <div class="badge">
            <span data-key="brandName" data-title="3M WATER FILTRATION PRODUCTS" data-text="3M WATER FILTRATION PRODUCTS">3M WATER FILTRATION PRODUCTS</span>
            <span id="removeFilter" class="filter-result-remove">x</span>              
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's still not working even after giving display and width.  
{
display:inline-block;
}

Comment: <div id="search-filter1" class="collapse in">
    <div class="filter-margin">
        <div class="search-optionfilter"><span class="activeFiltersCross">Active Filters:</span>
            <ul class="chosen-choices">
                <li class="search-choice">
                    <div class="badge"><span data-key="brandName" data-title="3M WATER FILTRATION PRODUCTS" data-text="3M WATER FILTRATION PRODUCTS">3M WATER FILTRATION PRODUCTS</span> <span id="removeFilter" class="filter-result-remove">x</span></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: CSS

div.filter-search div.collapse div.search-optionfilter ul.chosen-choices .badge {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 31ch;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 31ch;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 4px 20px 4px 10px;
    color: #151b1e;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

.badge {
    min-width: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}